# Redux State is stored in Primary Memory (or) Secondary Memory?

Tags: reactjs, caching, redux, react-state-management

I am currently working on react app, in which the landing page makes a request to **two different API's** and combine them and displays the result.

So, I am thinking to cache this data object in redux store so that whenever user goes back to the landing page, if data is already is present, fetch from redux store else make a new request.

**So my question is that when the object is stored in redux state, where is it actually stored -**

1. `Primary Memory(RAM)`  or
2. `Secondary Memory(HDD)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Redux state is just a variable. It is stored in RAM unless your computer runs out of resources and needs to swap to HDD. But that is true for every variable and not specific to Redux or even JavaScript, but an Operating System behaviour.